# Count out object within mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, redux

I have an object built as:

```
{
 id: // should be === to parentId  
    0: {id: "", parentId: ""} 
    1: {id: "", parentId: ""}
}
```

I somehow want to take this object and modify it within `mapStateToProps`

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const { id } = ownProps
    return {
        comments: state.comments 

    }
}
```

So that `comments:` return the length of my object. Like state.comments.length but it ain't working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects generally don't have a length property.

You could count the number of entries in the object by first converting its keys to an array by doing `Object.keys(state.comments).length`.